# Remove commits from remote without force pushing

Tags: git, github

I need to reset the `origin/branch` to 2 commits back:

```
a---b---c[head]---d---e[origin/branch]
```

to

```
a---b---c[head, origin/branch]
```

However **I can't force push to this branch** as it is protected on github.

What is the procedure to basically erase the last two commits from remote (github)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A force push is the only way to remove commits. However you can create a new commit that undoes what what changed in previous commits using `git revert`.

In your case, to undo the changes from commits `d` and `e`, you would do

```
git revert d e
```

Then you just need to commit the changes and push to origin.